# Estimating parameters of a known function with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

Given a function f(x, th) = **th_0** + **th_1***sin(x_1) + **th_2**x_1x_2, i.e. it is linear in the parameter **th**, while nonlinear in x. How do I then estimate the value of th so that it fits the target value, an array **y**? I know that if we just want to estimate a linear function I'd use `np.linalg.solve(x.T.dot(x), x.T.dot(y))`, but how do I fit these parameters to most closely match the function f?

Comment: Do you have ordered pairs of `(x_1, x_2)` ? If so, for each `(x_1, x_2) in ordered_pairs` you calculate `sin(x_1)` and `x_1 * x_2`, which will give you a list of your dependent variables. You then just fit an OLS with (a constant) to fit these points.

Comment: Would this then use numpy.lstsq?

Comment: See `statsmodels.OLS`: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html